# sharing GIF image url

Tags: html-table, javascript-objects

I'm new to java scripting but i have an idea about it, so I was planing to open blog for sharing GIF pictures to Facebook, now i'm facing a little problem when i share my blog post which is an image it doesn't show the image as GIF like giphy site, i was wondering if there is a sharing script like GIPHY site script so the sharing from the blogger will be posted as the original image link not the post link, i hope i explain it right thank you in advance.

This is my sharing method:

```
<li class='sharetext'>Share The Gag</li>

<div class='sright'>
   <li class='twitter'><a expr:href='&quot;http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;&amp;url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank' title='Tweet This !'><i class='fa fa-twitter'/></a>    </li>

   <li class='facebook'><a expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot; + data:post.url + &quot;&amp;t=&quot; + data:post.title' target='_blank' title='Share On Facebook !'><i class='fa fa-facebook'/></a>    </li>

   <li class='gplus'><a expr:href='&quot;https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=&quot; + &quot;en&amp;url=&quot; + data:post.url' target='_blank' title='Share On Google Plus !'><i class='fa fa-google-plus'/></a>    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set og:image meta tag. giphy is using it, and it should allow facebook to pick image from your site. You can read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup